# How to delay SplashScreen of Redux Persist Gate?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I'm using Redux and Redux-Persist to persist some user's data when the application closes.

There's an option called loading that you set up into PersistGate where you can specify a loading screen which will show while Redux-Persist is gathering the persisted data.

The problem is that this screen shows up and disappears too quick, and I would like to see it for a couple seconds.

**Is there any form to delay the transition of the loading screen?**
Here's my code, the entry point of the app:

```html
class App extends Component {    

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={ <SplashScreen />} persistor={persistor}>
          <Routes />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know if this will fits completely your needs, but maybe you can use the following workaround using the event onBeforeLift to call an action just before the gate lift to set a conditional render with a fixed timeout.

```js
class App extends Component {    

  state = {
    gateLifted: false
  }
  
  onBeforeLift = () => {
    // Take an action before the gate lifts
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.setState({ gateLifted: true}) 
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor} onBeforeLift={this.onBeforeLift}>
          { this.state.gateLifted ? <Routes /> : <SplashScreen />}
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try that

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else wanting to do this, you can use this:

```js
class App extends Component {    
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate
          loading={<SplashScreen />}
          persistor={persistor}
          onBeforeLift={() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000))}
        >
          <Routes />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.